# I want to see the bottleneck in my code, but I can't run shark (in xcode). How do I run shark?

Tags: xcode, profiler

When I click Run > Run with performance tool > shark, the program runs, but nothing else happens. Btw, I'm running this on the latest mac os

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shark hasn't been updated in nearly three years. Use Instruments to profile your program. The Time Profiler instrument helps you find the slow spots in your code. The version of Instruments that ships with Xcode 4.2 includes the Event Profiler and Counters instruments, which are a replacement for Shark's low-level profiling capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

For finding ways to speed up your code, *[random pausing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024)* works in any language or OS.

For a quick demo of how it works, there's a PDF slideshow *[here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/randompausedemo/files/)*.